# makeHttpRequest is undefined for object

Tags: android

hello Guys this my code I got this error The method makeHttpRequest(String, String, List)

is undefined for the type JSONParser

how to handle this problem please someone help me out 
and why makeHttpRequest is undefined for JSONParser

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: can you post some relevant code?

Comment: Didn't I saw this very same question about ~1 hour ago?

Comment: What API are you using? Who is `jsonParser`?

Comment: look this is my cod e

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                // Setup the get request
HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:8080");
                try{
                    // Execute the request in the client
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
                    // Grab the response
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                    json = reader.readLine();                       
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.d("Error",e.toString());
                    }
```